# Why flutter scheduleMicrotask method not call as expected?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want see what happend underlying `scheduleMicrotask` ,So I add a litte prints-code in *flutter-source-code*:
[image]
and
[image]
both source-code are in ***sky_engine\lib\async\schedule_microtask.dart***

Here is my main method:

```
import 'dart:async';

main(){
  scheduleMicrotask(() {
    print('task1');
  });
  scheduleMicrotask(() {
    print('task2');
  });
}
```

My question is : Why nethier prints show in output log ,nor break on breakpoint
?

logs just was:

```
task1
task2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is here： [flutter/issues/104235](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/104235#issuecomment-1134196063)